# I am getting an error, while adding DesignGridLayout to my register form. Please help me with this

Tags: java, swing, layout

My question is do we have to import designgridlayout package or something to the program for using the DesignGridLayout? or is the error due to some other thing?
If yes where can i get the package, and where do i install it(which directory). I am currently using jdk 1.7 and i use notepad for my programs. I am a beginner. Please help. My Code looks like this.

```
Register.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    
{

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)

    {

    JIF1.setVisible(true);
    }
}); 
    JIF1 = new JInternalFrame("Register",true,true, true, true);

    JIF1.setBounds(25, 25, 400, 300); 

    C1 = JIF1.getContentPane();
DesignGridLayout layout = new DesignGridLayout();
C1.setLayout(layout);

layout.row().grid(i1l1).add(i1t1);
```

The error I am getting is error:

```
cannot find symbol
DesignGridLayout = new DesignGridLayout();
Symbol: Class: DesignGridLayout
location: class a
```

Image of new error
[image]

Comment: _i use notepad for my programs_ Take a look at using an IDE, it'll manage the classpath for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DesignGridLayout` is a non-standard layout manager. Provided you have the [jar file](https://java.net/projects/designgridlayout/downloads/download/designgridlayout-1.11.jar) on your classpath you can add

```
import net.java.dev.designgridlayout.DesignGridLayout;
```

The location of the jar file doesn't matter as long as you specify the it's location at compile & runtime

However using an [IDE](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Java_IDEs) will make specifying the classpath for the JAR file a lot easier.

Comment: Thanks a lot Reimeus. I have added the jar file to class path and the designgridlayout error is solved. But, i am now in to a new problem, the command javac a.java command compiles the program. But when i try to run it using java a, it says could not find or load main class a.

Comment: You need to explicitly include the location of your `a` class in the classpath

Comment: well i have set classpath=C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin\Toms\Project
path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin
my a.java & a.class file are in the Project folder.
It compiles properly, but when i try to run using a.java it gives error message could not find or load class file.
I tried using java -cp "." a ... which loads my JFrame but with no components and some error showing up at cmd.
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:net.java.dev.designgridlayout.DesignGridLayout
....
....

Comment: Include locations of _both_ a.class and the jar on your runtime classpath - `java -cp .;design.jar a`

Comment: Reimeus i tried but not working for me. i have added an image of error to my previous question. My project submission is on monday and a way to go and i am stuck up here.

Comment: From that screenshot the jar file is not in the current folder - copy it into the current folder & it will work

Comment: Hey Reimeus, it works fine now. Now , i can continue with my project. Thanks a lot for the infos. Hoping to get your help in case i get stuck again. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you import your swing classes?

```
import javax.swing.*;
```

Comment: import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.SpringLayout;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

This much i have added.

Comment: DesignGridLayout is not part of standard swing; hence importing swing packages won't help at all.